# Cannot get jQuery-UI dialog to open with dynamically created links

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

OK, strange issue here.

I have the following code:

```
<script>
$("#calendar_container").on("click",".day-header-link", function(e){

    refreshDialog();

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("href"),
        success: function(data){
            $(".hover-form").empty().append(data).dialog("open");
        }
    });

    return false;
});
</script>
```

Pretty simple and straightforward, works like a charm when the links that are clicked are not dynamically loaded. When they are dynamically loaded, I get the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).empty(...).append(...).dialog is not a function
```

I have put the referenced div into the non-dynamic part of the page, I have initialized the dialog with the following function as well, which is referenced in the snippet above.

```
function refreshDialog(){
    //kick up the hover form stuff
    $(".hover-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        draggable: false,
        minWidth:350,
        minHeight: 200,
        modal: true,
        buttons: [
            {
            text: "Close",
            icons: false,
            click: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }


            }
        ]
    });
}
```

If it is relevant, here is the snippet that dynamically loads the next month in the calendar.

```
$("#calendar_container").on("click","#previous_month",function(e){

    //get data from link
    res = $(this).attr("href");
    res = res.replace("schedule","ajax");
    res = res.replace("view","standalone_calendar");

    $("#calendar_container").empty();
    $("#calendar_container").html("<img src=\""+BASE_URL+"/images/loading.gif\" alt=\"loading\" />");

    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        url: res,
        method: "post",
        data: "",
        success: function(c){
            $("#calendar_container").empty().append(c);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
$("#calendar_container").on("click","#next_month",function(e){

    //get data from link
    res = $(this).attr("href");
    res = res.replace("schedule","ajax");
    res = res.replace("view","standalone_calendar");

    $("#calendar_container").empty();
    $("#calendar_container").html("<img src=\""+BASE_URL+"/images/loading.gif\" alt=\"loading\" />");

    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        url: res,
        method: "post",
        data: "",
        success: function(c){
            $("#calendar_container").empty().append(c);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Not sure but think you want "delegated" events (the 'on' refers to a DOM object that contains all your dynamic links).   See also http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @JohnHascall from what I can tell (without the markup) it looks like the OP is delegating to the `#calendar_container` element with clicks originating from `day-header-link` elements. Hard to tell without a verifiable example.

Comment: #calendar_container is a static element within the page that holds the dynamic links that are to open the dialog. The .hover_form class is also a static element on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but I moved the call to my refreshDialog() function into the ajax success portion and everything is working smoothly.